# HTTP push to Unix hosts

Tags: http, unix, comet

Is it possible to push something (maybe a text snippet) to n number(1000s) of Unix hosts over HTTP using comet or something like that?

Basically my requirement is to transfer a text file to multiple Unix hosts at one go; currently I am using SSH and its rather slow :(

I thought to cron a poll through wget/curl but that causes lots of unwanted traffic.

Any insights please?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Udpcast](http://udpcast.linux.lu) - might of might not be what you are looking for. Here is [some guy's blog](http://kylecordes.com/2008/multicast-your-db-backups-with-udpcast) about using it.

Comment: That looks as useful as it does interesting! :)

Answer (score 1):

Comet is unrelated to this, each client will still have its own connection. If you have control of the network you could use multicast to send it in one go. Or if you have control of the clients you could have them all forward it to each other to spread the load out from the first pc.